# How to implement kafka-connect using apache-kaka instead of confluent

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I would like to use an open source version of kafka-connect instead of the confluent one as it appears that confluent cli is not for production and only for dev. I would like to be able to listen to changes on mysql database on aws ec2. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectapi). Period. If you want to use Kafka Connect you can do so with any modern distribution of Apache Kafka.

You then need a connector plugin to use with Kafka Connect, specific to your source technology. For integrating with a database there are [various considerations](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc), and available for MySQL you specifically have:

- [Kafka Connect JDBC](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/index.html) - see it in action [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/)
- [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) - see it in action [here](https://rmoff.net/2018/03/24/streaming-data-from-mysql-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect-and-debezium/)

The Confluent CLI is just a tool for helping manage and deploy Confluent Platform on developer machines. Confluent Platform itself is widely used in production.